# Access SQL multiple tables result dependent on result

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I'm a SQL newbie and need some help with linking 3 tables in Access. Each order has differnt size type from SIZE_TABLE. I need a SQL statement that produces below query result:

| Item | Color | Size | Size*Qty | UPCCode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

Thank you!

ORDER_TABLE:

| ID | ProductID | Color | SizeType | Size1Qty | Size2Qty | Size3Qty | Size4Qty | Size5Qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Item1 | Black | A | 0 | 20 | 20 | 10 | 0 |
| 2 | Item2 | Red | B | 15 | 25 | 25 | 15 | 5 |
| 3 | Item3 | White | C | 10 | 15 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | Item4 | Yellow | D | 20 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

SIZE_TABLE:

| ID | SizeType | Size | Size_Num |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | XS | Size1 |
| 2 | A | S | Size2 |
| 3 | A | M | Size3 |
| 4 | A | X | Size4 |
| 5 | A | XL | Size5 |
| 6 | B | 30 | Size1 |
| 7 | B | 32 | Size2 |
| 8 | B | 34 | Size3 |
| 9 | B | 36 | Size4 |
| 10 | B | 38 | Size5 |
| 11 | C | SM | Size1 |
| 12 | C | ML | Size2 |
| 13 | D | OS | Size1 |

BARCODE_TABLE:

| ID | ProductID | Color | Price | Size | UPCCode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Item1 | Black | $99 | XS | 7229473512 |
| 2 | Item2 | Red | $59 | 30 | 7229475516 |
| 3 | Item3 | White | $69 | OS | 7229474902 |
| 4 | Item4 | Yellow | $49 | XL | 7229474902 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Comment: You can INNER JOIN these 3 tables.

Comment: You do not have sizes to `ORDER_TABLE`. You have as column which database engine can not recognize. Still you can achieve it but you have write a union query and select query for each size column. But it would be best if you make column `Size` in ORDER_TABLE. Then can join other tables easily.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use UNION query to rearrange Order_Table to normalized structure then use that query in subsequent query to join with other tables

```
SELECT ID, ProductID, Color, SizeType, Size1Qty AS Qty, "Size1" AS Size FROM Order_Table 
UNION SELECT ID, ProductID, Color, SizeType, Size2Qty, "Size2" FROM Order_Table
UNION SELECT ID, ProductID, Color, SizeType, Size3Qty, "Size3" FROM Order_Table
UNION SELECT ID, ProductID, Color, SizeType, Size4Qty, "Size4" FROM Order_Table
UNION SELECT ID, ProductID, Color, SizeType, Size5Qty, "Size5" FROM Order_Table;
```

To avoid UNION query, normalize data structure. Create a dependent table that relates to Order_Table. Call it OrderDetails_Table.

ID | OrderID_FK | ProductID | Qty

Order_Table should have fields for OrderID, CustID, OrderDate.